# Getting date & time values from date time picker in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I m using date & time picker in blackberry.
  I want to show the selected date & time in a field.
  Here is the code i m using.

```
            DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance();
            datePicker.doModal();
            Calendar cal = datePicker.getDateTime();
            Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = DateTimePicker.createInstance(Calendar.getInstance(), null,     "HH:mm");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();   

 UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {              
            public void run() { 
            if(dateTimePicker.doModal()) {

            calendar = dateTimePicker.getDateTime();
            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            long longDate = date.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            String eventstring = dateFormat.format(date);
            Dialog.inform("You have selected time =="+eventstring)      

        }

    }
});
```